# Local personalisations for Vagrant boxes?

Tags: unix, provisioning, chef-infra, vagrant

As a developer, if I want each and every vagrant box I build from any repository to include my customisations, how would I achieve that?

For example, I have my own [vim](http://www.vim.org/) config, my own [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) config, my own [git](http://git-scm.com/) config, plus there are certain command-line tools I expect on every `unix` environment I use, such as the aforementioned plus [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

I would hope [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) would include the ability to customise local versions of checked-out box configurations, but I couldn't find out how to do it.

I can't use the normal [Vagrantfile](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/vagrantfile.html) because this comes from the repository. I can't create a custom [base box](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html), because the `Vagrantfile` that is checkout out from the repository specifies which base box it wants to use.

Currently the best way I've come up with is to create a [repository containing my configs](https://github.com/nottrobin/.shellconfig/) and set it up when I first log in to a newly built Vagrant box by installing all the software I expect through `apt-get` and then importing my configuration files, but clearly this is frustrating if I'm building a lot of boxes.

Does anyone know how I can automate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually a bunch of `Vagrantfile`s, loaded in a [specific order](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/vagrantfile.html#vagrantfile_load_order).

The one that's meant for personal/local customisations is located in `~/.vagrant.d/`, so any changes you want applied to all boxes build by you, just put them in a `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`.

Voila!

Comment: And you could use this to add custom provisioning logic with chef or puppet, and pass a set of manifests in your home directory, which could be shared across all boxes